# How to write same custom modules and import other module?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

When using the TypeScript in vs.net 2013, I am writting same custom module m1 files:

MyClass1.ts:

```
module m1{
  export class MyClass1{
    test1(){
    }
  }
}
```

MyClass2.ts:

```
/// <reference path="MyClass1.ts" />
import Flux = require("flux");
module m1{
  class MyFluxDispatcher extends Flux.Dispatcher<any>{
    ...
  }
  export class MyClass2{
    test2(){
      var c1 = new m1.MyClass1();   <--- Error 81 Property 'MyClass1' does not exist on type 'typeof m1'.
    }
  }
}
```

How to write same custom module in multi files and import other module ?
and I will using those with requirejs:

main.js:

```
import m1 = require("m1");
var a1 = new m1.MyClass2();
...
```

in html:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modules the way you are is kind of useless when working with commonjs/require since each file is in it self a "module". There is a section about [CommonJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) on the requires site where you can read a bit more about this. Also learn more about CommonJS it self, since it is closely connected to how requires and typescript works together.

Doing something like this should work better for you:

*MyClass1.ts*

```js
export default class MyClass1 {
    test1() {

    }
}
```

*MyClass2.ts*

```js
import MyClass1 from "./MyClass1.ts";

export default class MyClass2 {
    test2() {
        var c1 = new MyClass1();
    }
}
```

There is lots of information about this if you search for it, a good place to start is looking at CommonJS and RequireJS and just learn how it works. Hope this helps, get back to mi if you have any questions.

Comment: But I need run AMD JS on internet browser, the CommonJS is for Server side.

and I hope Typescript One File Per Class in same module.